# Lua : Dynamically calling a function with arguments

Tags: lua, dynamic-function

Using Lua, I'm trying to dynamically call a function with parameters.
I want to send a string to be parsed in a way that:

- 1st argument is a class instance "Handle"
- 2nd is the function to be called
- All that is left are arguments

"modules" is a a table like `{ string=<instance of a class> }`
split() is a simple parser that returns a table with indexed strings.

```
function Dynamic(msg)
    local args = split(msg, " ")
    module = args[1]
    table.remove(args, 1)
    if module then
        module = modules[module]
        command = args[1]
        table.remove(args, 1)
        if command then
            if not args then
                module[command]()
            else
                module[command](unpack(args))  -- Reference 1
            end
        else
            -- Function doesnt exist
        end
    else
        -- Module doesnt exist
    end
end
```

When I try this with "ignore remove bob", by "Reference 1", it tries to call "remove" on the instance associated with "ignore" in modules, and gives the argument "bob", contained in a table (with a single value).

However, on the other side of the call, the remove function does not receive the argument. I even tried to replace the "Reference 1" line with

```
module[command]("bob")
```

but I get the same result.

Here is the other function, which does not receive the argument `"bob"` :

```
function TIF_Ignore:remove(name)
    print(name)  -- Reference 2
    TIF_Ignore:rawremove(name)
    TIF_Ignore:rawremovetmp(name)
    print(title.. name.. " is not being ignored.")
end
```

I added "Reference 2" in my code when I was trying to figure out what was wrong. When I do "ignore remove bob", or when I replace the "unpack(args)" with "bob" on "Reference 1", the variable "name" in "remove" is still nil.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What does the "other side" look like.

Comment: And what does the function 'split' look like, because it's not part of standard Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration `function TIF_Ignore:remove(name)` is equivalent to `function TIF_Ignore.remove(self, name)`. Note the use of colon in the first case, it adds extra hidden parameter to emulate OOP and classes. The way you call the function, you pass "bob" as the `self` parameter instead of `name`.

To fix this you can make `remove` "static function" like this: `function TIF_Ignore.remove(name)`. However, you'll also have to change `rawremove` and `rawremovetmp` in a similar fashion, both declaration and calling site. The other (easier) option is not to remove `module` from the `args` table, it should be the first parameter passed.

Comment: Thanks! I choosed this anwser as "best" because you pinpointed the problem. I'm not experienced in Lua and I just want to "get this thing working", and you made it happen! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call a function defined with the colon `:` syntax, you have to pass it an additional argument, namely the table it is expecting.  Because the particular example you give does not use `self`, you could switch to the dot `.` syntax, but in case you need the full generality, look to the code below:

```
function Dynamic(msg)
    local args   = split(msg, " ")
    local module = table.remove(args, 1)
    if module and modules[module] then
        module = modules[module]
        local command = table.remove(args, 1)
        if command then
            local command = module[command]
            command(module, unpack(args))
        else
            -- Function doesnt exist
        end
    else
        -- Module doesnt exist
    end
end
```

I have also fixed a number of minor problems:

- Variables should be `local`.
- `args` is always non-nil.
- Lookup `modules[module]` might fail.
- `table.remove` returns the element removed, and it's OK to call it on an empty table.

Comment: Thanks, you're anwser helped me point a good number of other problem I was not aware of, and needed to fix!!